# CPP Syntax Highlighting for Google Colab?

Tags: c++, google-colaboratory, syntax-highlighting

Any suggestions to implement C++ syntax highlighting for Google Colab code cells?

I looked into the following Jupyter extension with support for C++ syntax highlighting:
https://github.com/aldanor/ipybind

Syntax highlighting works fine when I load this extension on my local Jupyter installation. However, syntax highlighting does not work when this extension is installed and loaded on Colab.

I am okay with compiling the C++ code manually. I would like to stay with standard c++ compilers, hence, not looking into xeus-cling.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple [extension](https://gist.github.com/akshaykhadse/7acc91dd41f52944c6150754e5530c4b) to solve my use case.